# Premiere vs Vegas performance in i7 CPU?

Tags: video, premiere, editing, vegas-pro, windows

Excluding other computer components, which timeline editor is better optimized for timeline editing for Intel i7 CPU (4790k) in Windows 8.1 64 bit?

Note: Timeline editing is important (Not render speed).

Comment: I don't believe there can be a  answer to your question, as there are many other factors all of which impact performance: footage codec, hard drive I/o speeds, RAM available. However, Premiere is both a professional program (opposed to Vegas' consumer), and supports using your graphics card, if it is CUDA-enabled.